# PHP getting an automated sql data to be deleted

Tags: php, mysql

I've been asked to create a Timesheet based on PHP and mySQL.

I've created a page to insert the data and another page to show the data and edit/delete the data shown.

Here is the page to show the data and edit/delete them:

```
<?php
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
?>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="job" id="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>" value="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $info['job_code'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $info['job_desc'] ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $info['job_client'] ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $info['job_year'] ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $info['job_month']?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $info['job_date']?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $info['job_category']?> </td>
    <td>EDIT</td>
    <td>DELETE</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

and here's the deleting process

```
 $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$admin_data_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs")or die(mysql_error());
$job_code_query = $_POST['job'];
$job_code_query_items = 'IN ( ';
foreach ($job_code_query as $key => $value) {
    $job_code_query_items .= ($key > 0 ? ", '" . $value . "'" : "'" . $value . "'");
}
$job_code_query_items .= ' );';
while ($admin_data = mysql_fetch_array($admin_data_query)) {
    if (isset($_POST[$admin_data['job_code']])) {
        $admin_sql = "DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_code = $job_code_query_items";
        $admin_query = mysql_query($admin_sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $this->messages[] = "Job deleted.";
    } else {
        $this->messages[] = "Failed to delete job.";
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the variable of job[] in the 2nd page didn't catch the user submitted checkbox in page 1, or the first page didn't send the data because the checkbox value(maybe i wrote it wrong)

EDIT: I've found the answer, here are the correct code:

in page 1

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>"
           id="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>"
           value="<?php echo $info['job_code']?>"/>
</td>
<td><?php echo $info['job_code'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $info['job_desc'] ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $info['job_client'] ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $info['job_year'] ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $info['job_month']?> </td>
<td><?php echo $info['job_date']?> </td>
<td><?php echo $info['job_category']?> </td>
```

in processing page (2)

```
 while ($admin_data = mysqli_fetch_array($admin_data_query)) {
    $job_code_query = $admin_data["job_code"];

    if (isset($_POST[$admin_data["job_code"]])) {

        $admin_sql = "DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_code = '$job_code_query'";
        $admin_query = mysqli_query($this->db_connection, $admin_sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->db_connection));
        $this->messages[] = "Job deleted.";
    } else {
        $this->messages[] = "Failed to delete job.";
    }
}
```

Thank you for anyone who have tried to help or read it!

Comment: if you have single checkbox don't make it as array just type `name="job"`. you can always use `isset` to check if theckbos is set and take it value but IMO making name of checkbox as single value not as array will do the trick

Comment: What if there are many job listed and i want to delete them when the multiple checkboxes are checked? I've tried the answer MaveRick posted and your suggestion, there aren't anymore error, but my job didn't deleted/still listed.

Comment: if you send your query with out this variable this will delete the entire table `jobs` what you need to delete exactly to be clear with my answer

Answer (score 0):

change `$job_code_query = $_POST['job[]'];` to `$job_code_query = $_POST['job'];`

but this will cause another problem since `$job_code_query` is an array so you can't send an array to the query `$admin_sql ="DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_code = '$job_code_query'";`

you have to fix the above definition and convert your array to string before adding it in the query

you code would be:

```
$this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    $admin_data_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs")or die(mysql_error());
    $job_code_query = $_POST['job'];
    $job_code_query_items = 'IN ( ';
    foreach ($job_code_query as $key => $value) {
        $job_code_query_items .= ($key>0?", '".$value."'":"'".$value."'");
    }
    $job_code_query_items .= ' );';
    while ($admin_data = mysql_fetch_array($admin_data_query)) {
        if (isset($_POST['job_code'])) {
            $admin_sql ="DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_code $job_code_query_items";
            $admin_query = mysql_query($admin_sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $this->messages[] = "Job deleted.";
        } else {
            $this->messages[] = "Failed to delete job.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've followed your suggestion, but the job are still listed in the database. And I'm still confused about how to convert the array to string. Can you provide more information? Thank You!

Comment: `$job_code_query` is an array that means it has many values, do you need to delete many rows in one time up to these values of this array?

Comment: Yes, basically it's like the checkboxes in email inboxes, I want to delete many rows in one time.

Comment: I've changed the code to yours, but it still didn't delete the data in my database. Thank you for your help up until now though! Do you think that the problem lies when I tried to submit the list of job data in 1st Page?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line 29 by that one

```
$job_code_query = $_POST['job'];
```

You should also use PDO or MySQLi instead mysql_* functions,  which are now deprecated. 
With a MySQLi conection, you HAVE to use `$dbconnection->query($sqlquery)` and no `mysql_query`